# C++ Comparator function to specifiy specific key ordering for map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparator

**Question:** How would you write a function to do a custom comparator for a map constructor to create a specific order for keys?

I have the following string keys:

```
"a", "d", "i", "n", "ns", "ne", "vl", "rr"
```

I am using a map to write values for those keys. But I need them to be ordered in that exact order as stated above. Map usually creates the order:

```
a d i n ne ns rr vl
```

How do I write a comparator function that I can send to the map constructor so I can keep this order?

**Here's what I've resorted to for now**

```
vector<pair<string, string>>({ { "a","" },{ "d","" },{ "i","" },{ "n","" },{ "ns","" },{ "ne","" },{ "vl","" },{ "rr","" }, { "","" } });
```

...and then I do a bunch of find_if calls. If it is found, I add the value to the pair. If not, I create a new pair (at the beginning). I do it at the beginning so I can just return "" if the key does not exist. Well, it all works except that I need to sort the keys that I don't list above, as any key can be added. Also, my program crashes when I try to add a non-existent key. Gotta debug that... but this way of doing it is confusing. Using a map with a bit of specific sorting would be perfect for my needs (any keys added during runtime should be sorted by a default comparison as well to maintain an order. These "unknown" (future-added) keys can be sorted however).

**Reason that I "want this" (asked in comments)**: I need to, at the final step of my program, output a string like this:

```
",a=legato,d=dn,i=12,n=A3"
```

etc. They need to be in a specific order because I need to later use regex (in a separate program) to manipulate this string. The order is important for specified keys. The order must be also fixed for unspecified keys... because of regex.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Usually you want the comparator function to be something simple and fast. If I were you I would consider, keeping the `vector<pair<string,string>>` structure, and also, making a `map<string, unsigned int>` that maps strings to their indices and using that for fast lookup. Or you can use `boost::multiindex::container` if you don't want to worry about keeping the details of keeping the two structures consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is how you would create comparator function for map to create a specific sort order for a number of keys.**

The inspiration from other answers allowed me to write my own answer that addresses my question exactly and in the best way possible (IMO).

RUN: https://ideone.com/7H5CZg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// create vector holding desired ordering
vector<string> order({ "a", "d", "i", "n", "ns", "ne", "vl", "rr" });

// create sort function for map   
struct my_comparator {
    bool operator()(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
        // find() - it.begin() gives you the index number. 
        int a = find(order.begin(), order.end(), s1) - order.begin();
        int b = find(order.begin(), order.end(), s2) - order.begin();
        return a < b; // lower index < higher index
    }
};

int main() {
    // create the map
    map<string,string, my_comparator> MyMap = { { "a","legato" }, { "i","3" }, { "vl","3" }, { "rr","2" } };

    // output map
    for (auto& it : MyMap) cout << it.first << "=" << it.second << "  ";

    return 0;
}
```

output: `a=legato  i=3  vl=3  rr=2`

---

**UPDATE: This will usually be faster, it uses a map instead of vector to look up key order.**

You can apply this way of doing things to the other answers as well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// using a map is faster in most cases (with more keys and such)
map<string, int> maporder({ {"a", 1}, {"d", 2}, {"i", 3}, {"n", 4}, {"ns", 5}, {"ne", 6}, {"vl", 7}, {"rr", 8} });

// create sort function for map   
struct mapcomp {
    bool operator()(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
         // compares ints by looking them up with the input string
        return maporder[s1] < maporder[s2];
    }
};

int main() {
    // create the map
    map<string,string, mapcomp> MyMap = { { "a","legato" }, { "i","3" }, { "vl","3" }, { "rr","2" } };

    // output map
    for (auto& it : MyMap) cout << it.first << "=" << it.second << "  ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You specify the comparator that map uses for ordering keys as a template parameter. So your map declaration looks like:

```
std::map<string, value_type, my_comparator> my_map;
```

The comparator is something you can define that takes two `key_type` parameters `a` and `b`, and then returns true if `a` comes before `b` (and false otherwise). An example of this would be:

```
struct my_comparator {
    bool operator()(const string &a, const string &b) {
        // Return true if a comes before b.
    }
}
```

To achieve the ordering that you have specified in your question, you could do something along the lines of the below. I have used `std::tuple` to ensure the strict ordering criteria is met.

```
bool operator()(const string &a, const string &b) {
    auto a_tuple = std::make_tuple(a == "a", a == "d", a == "i", ..., a);
    auto b_tuple = std::make_tuple(b == "a", b == "d", a == "i", ..., a);

    return a_tuple < b_tuple;
}
```

As this has `a` and `b` in the last elements of the tuple, it will sort by these if it does not match one of your pre-defined strings.

Comment: Another thing I just realized... I dunno if this would work, but what If I convert the map to a vector, and then do a sort with this comparator, that would mean I only use this complex comparison once when I export the string, instead of every time I add or remove a key in the map,

Comment: just not sure how to translate that to a sort comparator, sorry I know I am asking a lot (I know how to use sort and basic lambda functions).

Comment: auto comparator = [](const pair<string, string> &a, const pair<string, string> &b) { ... }

Comment: for the sake of correctness `a_tuple < b_tuple;` it turned out that I needed `>` to get the right order.

Comment: Thanks ajshort, implemented it (not tested, but no IDE errors). Just want to say I am actually learning. I'm looking at all the examples here and I'm starting to understand better how the different classes work, how to access elements, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the edit to the question explaining why this is wanted, I'd recommend instead using a `map` with default ordering, then at the time you want to output the values consult a different list:

```
std::vector<std::string> ordering = { "a", "d", "i", "n", "ns", "ne", "vl", "rr" };
for (const auto& key : ordering)
    ...output the_map[key]...
```

Anyway, if you insist on a `map` with different ordering, you can special-case as necessary:

```
struct WeirdLess
{
    bool operator<(const std:string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const
    {
        if (lhs == "ne" && rhs == "ns" ||
            lhs == "ns" && rhs == "ne" ||
            lhs == "rr" && rhs == "vl ||
            lhs == "vl" && rhs == "rr")
            return rhs < lhs;
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
};

std::map<std::string, std::string, WeirdLess> my_map;
```

It's not very scalable though, if you end up with hundreds of entries in the `map` and half of those need special casing.  Trying to come up with some logic capturing why particular strings are earlier - or at least an heuristic for recognising them - that may be a better idea.  For example:

```
    bool operator<(const std:string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const
    {
        if (lhs.size() == 2 && rhs.size() == 2 && lhs[0] == rhs[0])
            return rhs < lhs;
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
```

Comment: `operator<` I think should be bool `operator()`

Comment: `"vl` needs to be `"vl"`

Comment: `std:string&` to `std::string&`

Comment: So you just added the "for each loop" to your answer. However, I don't know if this would work. The for each loop would simply end after my specified keys, but I also need to get unspecified keys.

Comment: @ElanHickler: fair enough - the question doesn't make that clear: I took "unspecified keys" therein to mean any of the set list of keys that wasn't explicitly set during the pre-output processing, but if you're not sure of the overall list of keys then that's indeed a problem.

Comment: yes, unspecified keys would be unkown keys, keys added during runtime. I won't know all the keys as there is a big convenience factor I am trying to create, basically: create new keys on the fly, and even possibly define new sorting order on the fly. I'll improve my question.

I could do something complex to maintain vector and map, but that's beyond this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Sorts a vector of pairs based on a vector holding key order**

This is not the answer to the original question, but a solution to the problem described. See my other answer for a faster version of this concept.

RUN: https://ideone.com/8ICRwZ

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

// create vector holding desired ordering
vector<string> order({ "a", "d", "i", "n", "ns", "ne", "vl", "rr" });

// create sort function for vector of pairs
bool comparator(const pair<string, string> &s1, const pair<string, string> &s2) {
    // find() - it.begin() gives you the index number. 
    int a = find(order.begin(), order.end(), s1.first) - order.begin();
    int b = find(order.begin(), order.end(), s2.first) - order.begin();
    return a < b; // lower index < higher index
};

int main() {
    // create the map
    map<string,string> MyMap = { { "a","legato" }, { "vl","3" }, {"i", "3"}, { "rr","2" } };

    // convert map into vector of pairs
    vector<pair<string,string>> vp;
    for (auto& it : MyMap) vp.push_back({ it.first, it.second });

    // sort the vector
    sort(vp.begin(), vp.end(), comparator);

    // put the vector pairs into a string format
    for (auto& it : vp) cout << it.first << "=" << it.second << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

output: `a=legato i=3 vl=3 rr=2`

Comment: I just tested in Visual Studio using tuple (ajshort answer) vs my answer using vector. Tuple is 2x faster in debug mode. Tuple is a little slower in release mode. In ideone, tuple is much slower... I have no idea how code profiling works.... Here's ideone version: https://ideone.com/KSccm1

Answer (score 0):

**This function sorts a set based on an input vector for ordering**

A good friend and great programmer wrote this answer for me. This is the most efficient solution according to ideone.com. This is not the answer to the original question, but it *is* the answer to the actual problem.

```
//first param is the container you want to sort
//second param is the container that holds the order of things
vector<pair<string,string>> KeySort(map<string,string> s, const vector<string>& order){
    vector<pair<string,string>> res;
    for (const auto& it : order) {
        auto needle = s.find(it);
        if (needle != s.end()) {
            res.emplace_back(move(*needle));
            s.erase(needle);
        }
    }
    for (auto&& it : s) res.emplace_back(move(it));
    return res;
}
```

ideone benchmark test: https://ideone.com/GYsiM8

ideone example use: https://ideone.com/eAU5US

```
// create vector holding desired ordering
vector<string> ord({ "a", "d", "i", "n", "ns", "ne", "vl", "rr" });

// create the map
map<string,string> MyMap = { {"a","legato"}, {"vl","4"}, 
{"i","2"}, {"rr","3"}, {"z","unspecified1"}, {"b","unspecified2"}};

// sort the vector
vector<pair<string,string>> out = KeySort(MyMap, ord);
```

output: `a=legato i=2 vl=4 rr=3 b=unspecified2 z=unspecified1`